# Select all tables where data was created in the last 10 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I can get data created in the last 10 minutes with

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE  created_dt > sysdate - interval '10' minute and created_dt < sysdate;
```

However, I need to find out all tables where data was created in the last 10 minutes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through multiple tables to execute same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326698/loop-through-multiple-tables-to-execute-same-query)

Comment: By `need to find out all tables where data was created in the last 10 minutes` did you mean that you have several tables where existed `created_dt` column and you want to check all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so as per my understanding you want list of all the tables where data was added/created in the last 10 minutes.

Here's my approach :

1. First get a list of all the tables which contain this column"created_Dt" first.
2. Loop over all these tables and check if data was added in the past 10 minutes.

& then Display number of rows added to each one of these tables.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE

CURSOR ALL_TABLES_NAME IS
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES "ALL"
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM all_cons_columns WHERE table_name = "ALL".TABLE_NAME AND COLUMN_NAME=UPPER('created_dt'));

ALL_TABLES_NAME_REC ALL_TABLES_NAME%rowtype;

row_count number;

BEGIN

OPEN ALL_TABLES_NAME;

LOOP

FETCH ALL_TABLES_NAME INTO ALL_TABLES_NAME_REC;
EXIT WHEN ALL_TABLES_NAME%notfound;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || ALL_TABLES_NAME_REC.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE created_dt > (SYSDATE-10/24/60)' INTO row_count;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table '|| ALL_TABLES_NAME_REC.table_name || ' has been updated with '|| row_count || ' new rows');


END LOOP;

CLOSE ALL_TABLES_NAME;

END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to enable flashback and then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table1 AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE;
```

You can query the data dictionary to find a list of all your tables and build a dynamic query for each and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to loop through all the tables.

If you don't have flashback enabled then you will need to have a `created_dt` column (or equivalent) on every table.

Answer (score -1):

If your tables have `MONITORING`, one approach is to just use the data dictionary to see table modifications.  Provided `MONITORING` is on, the below approach should let you see what tables have received `INSERT`s (or `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s, if desired) over a given time period.

The below approach has the disadvantage that one must actually wait 10 minutes before checking what has been created, but it doesn't require tables to have any particular column.

**Update: as per Ikrom's comment, the original answer was flawed by checking the data dictionary only once.  This answer has been updated to check twice to detect changes.**

This approach will record baseline table modification counts, then check back for any changes 10 minutes later.  It uses two work-tables one for reference `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF` and one to view the modified tables after 10 min `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE`:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
  ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
  AS SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS WHERE ROWNUM < 0;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
  ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
  AS SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS WHERE ROWNUM < 0;

Table created.
Table created.
```

After creating these work tables, one can detect any changes by taking initial state and comparing to final state after 10 minutes.  After running the below block, one can query `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE` to see what tables have been `INSERT`ed.

```
BEGIN
  --Flush monitoring info, to get a baseline.
  DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO();

  --Capture the initial state.
  INSERT INTO ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF
    SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS;
  COMMIT;

  -- Wait ten minutes.
  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(600);

  --Flush monitoring info, to get a snapshot for comparison.
  DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO();

  -- Capture the final state.
  INSERT INTO ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE
    SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF
    WHERE ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF.TABLE_OWNER = ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.TABLE_OWNER
          AND ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF.TABLE_NAME = ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.TABLE_NAME
          AND ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_REF.INSERTS >= ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.INSERTS);
  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

After running the block, check for tables with `INSERT`s:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE;
```

Here's an example to detect changes to one table over 10 mins, but to exclude the other since it has been 10+ minutes since its last `INSERT`:

Create test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RECENT_DML (THE_DATA NUMBER, DML_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL); 
CREATE TABLE NO_RECENT_DML (THE_DATA NUMBER, DML_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

Table created.
Table created.
```

And add some initial test-data in two tables.

```
INSERT INTO RECENT_DML (THE_DATA) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO NO_RECENT_DML (THE_DATA) VALUES (1);
COMMIT;

1 row inserted.
1 row inserted.
Commit complete.
```

Then run the monitoring block above in one session above to detect changes after 10 minutes.

While the block is running in the first session, add more data in a second session to only `RECENT_DML`.

```
INSERT INTO RECENT_DML (THE_DATA) VALUES (1);
COMMIT;

1 row inserted.
Commit complete.
```

After the block has completed in the first session, query for the modified tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS_COMPARE;

TABLE_NAME                    
RECENT_DML
```

Comment: by running this `BEGIN DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO();
END;` the table will contain `TIMESTAMP` of this process, not a table last DML time. For example, if a table was UPDATED 1 hour ago and you did `flush` now then it will show current time, not the real time when data was modified in a table OR need to run the command every ten minutes exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Ikrom that gives something to look into.  I updated to mention this and will experiment and update if there's a clean refinement.  Thanks

Comment: @Ikrom thanks for the feedback.  Indeed this approach needs to compare two points to exclude records outside the window.  Answer updated.